# test, if a page is empty or not

Tags: page

I need a macro for a test if a page has no text, means the current point is the upper left corner of the text area. This does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\isOnTopOfPage{%
  \ifdim \pagetotal > \pagegoal
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
   \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
foo bar \par
\isOnTopOfPage{>> On top of the page}%
  {>> not on top of the page}

\clearpage
\isOnTopOfPage{>> On top of the page}%
  {>> not on top of the page}

\end{document}
```

Edit 1: Problems are still lines without a `\par` and empty boxes. Only the second one is correct:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@secondofthree[3]{#2}
\newcommand*\isOnTopOfPage{%
  \ifdim\pagetotal=\z@
    \unless\ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen
      \expandafter\@gobbletwo
    \fi
    \expandafter\@secondofthree
  \fi
  \@secondoftwo
} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
f
\isOnTopOfPage{>> On top of the page}%
  {>> not on top of the page}

\clearpage
\isOnTopOfPage{>> On top of the page}%
  {>> not on top of the page}

\clearpage
\null% empty box
\isOnTopOfPage{>> On top of the page}%
  {>> not on top of the page}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While it is nice to have a short example and a focused question, maybe it would help to add a bit of context why you want to test for an empty page. Possibly existing/alternative solutions exist for what you want to do.

Comment: The first line on a page is usually formatted before the previous page is shipped, which means that you really need to be testing for a full page, not an empty one.  Preface your test with \needspace.

Comment: This is essentially not possible in tex, as page breaking happens asynchronouslly with line breaking and macro expansion. You need a two pass system, you can write the vertical position with `\pdfsavepos` and check it on the next run.

Comment: The third example doesn't yield the wrong output. If you put `\null` the following will *not* end up at the top of the page (you could use the `showframe` package to see this). But @DavidCarlisle is right, this is not really possible for each and every case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: ah yes, I forgot about it. Will see if it is possible with `\pdfsavepos`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the TeX book:

> When the current page contains no boxes, `\pagetotal` and its relatives are zero and `\pagegoal` is 16383.99998 pt (TeX’s largest ⟨dimen⟩);

So the following test does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@secondofthree[3]{#2}
\newcommand*\isOnTopOfPage{%
  \ifdim\pagetotal=\z@
    \unless\ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen
      \expandafter\@gobbletwo
    \fi
    \expandafter\@secondofthree
  \fi
  \@secondoftwo
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
foo bar \par
\isOnTopOfPage{>> On top of the page}%
  {>> not on top of the page}

\clearpage
\isOnTopOfPage{>> On top of the page}%
  {>> not on top of the page}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, but there is still a problem without a par in a first line or a an empty box.I modified my question.

Comment: the quote at the top is true, but the condition it states isn't the same as "the text at this position will end up at the top of a page" especially as the question (now) includes some tests mid-paragraph where you don't even know what page it will be on, let alone whetehr it will be at the top.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well, the first MWE was different. I know that this doesn't work mid paragraph.

Comment: @Skillmon sure I know you know, the comment wasn't aimed at you:-)